# SQL Выборка различий в таблицах

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть две таблицы, имеющие одинаковую структуру и одинаково заполненные по двум первым столбцам (`Group`, `DayOfWeek`), однако, последующие четыре могут иметь различия (`Les1`, `Les2`, `Les3`, `Les4`).

Необходимо выбрать таблицу, в которой в столбцах (`Les1`, `Les2`, `Les3`, `Les4`) будут только различия, между таблицами.

Comment: объедините выборку с обоих таблиц, сделайте группировку по искомым столбцам и подсчет количества строк.  оставьте только те, где количество равно единице

Comment: @teran а можно примерным запросом?

Comment: либо еще вариации с union/except /interset. либо джойном

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если подсчитать одинаковые строки в выборке, то уникальными (различными) будут те, где число будет равным 1.

пример на t-sql, с упрощенным набором данных:

```
declare @a table (g int, f1 int, f2 int);
declare @b table (g int, f1 int, f2 int);

insert into @a values 
    (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3), 
    (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3);   -- пересекаются
insert into @b values
    (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3),   -- пересекаются
    (1,3,1), (1,3,2), (1,3,3);

--select * from @a;
--select * from @b;

select f1, f2
from (
    select g, f1, f2 from @a
    union all 
    select g, f1, f2 from @b
) as t
group by f1,f2
having count(*) = 1
```

полное объединение таблиц с повторами через `union all`, группировка, и фильтрация по количеству

---

Либо, взять объединение таблиц, и вычесть их пересечение:

```
select f1, f2 from @a
union 
select f1, f2 from @b
except (
    select f1,f2 from @a 
    intersect 
    select f1,f2 from @b        
)
```

Comment: а возможен ли вывод, только совпадающих значений в строках (допустим, просто заменить совпадения нулем)?

Comment: @Gardenios не понял вас. дополните свой вопрос

Comment: ну вот сделана выборку по строкам, которые имеют различия, можно ли избавиться (может изменить значение) от ячеек, которые все же имеют совпадения

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно условие, но может поможет:

--выборка с первой таблицы записей (по уникальным полям ), которые отличаются от 2 таблицы

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE Group = t.Group AND DayOfWeek = t.DayOfWeek AND (Les1 <> t.Les1 OR Les2 <> t.Les2 OR Les3 <> t.Les3 OR Les4 <> t.Les4))
```

Comment: выборка нужна только с первой, а с обоих таблиц, кажется

Comment: оно выбирает хорошо, но дело в том, что если строки одинаковые, ее выбирать вообще не надо